# Google Analytics goal if user complete the goal next day in second visit

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, goal-tracking

I want to know how many of users that come to our page from sites A and B later complete the goal. Users come to our page from site A or site B. They don't complete the goal in current session. They come back to our site next day and they complete the goal in second visit.

From what I understand GA will set new goal if user complete the goal in current session. But as I wrote most users will finish the goal next days when coming back to the site. And this time referring site won't be the same but it will be direct or google traffic.

Is there any way to find out how many users from Source A completed the goal next days even if they come to site later from google?

Answer (score 1):

I found out this is called Multi-Channel Funnels and is already inside Google analytics under Conversions tab.

Comment: If you have goals already set up, if you look under Conversions>Multi-channel funnels>Time lag shows metrics on users that took 1 or more days to reach a goal.